# SQL count with equal, unknown values

Tags: sql

I have one table:

```
ID | domain       | address             | downloads
====================================================
 1 | example.com  | example.com/siteA   | 1
 2 | example.com  | example.com/siteB   | 2
 3 | example.com  | sub.example.com     | 1
 4 | example.com  | sub.example.com/dir | 2
 5 | foobar.com   | foobar.com/site123  | 1
 6 | foobar.com   | foobar.com/site     | 2
 ...
```

now I like to know how many "downloads" one domain has like

```
domain      | downloads
=======================
example.com | 6
foobar.com  | 3
```

my statement is currently

```
SELECT domain, COUNT(downloads) as downloads FROM table GROUP BY domain
```

but this returns (of course)

```
domain      | downloads
=======================
example.com | 4
foobar.com  | 2
```

**Please note that i don't know the domains so I can't use a condition!**

Comment: Instead of `COUNT(downloads)` you need `SUM(downloads)`.

Comment: How did it get the `9`? Shouldn't it be `4` and `2` in your example?

Comment: yep, sorry should be 4 and 2 of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`:

```
SELECT domain, SUM(downloads) as downloads 
FROM table 
GROUP BY domain
```

Comment: oh well that's embarrassing!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sum as below

```
select domain,sum(downloads) from tableA group by domain
```